# An error occurred while updating the product(s) status

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, error

When I select some products inside the product catalog and I try to update them, I get the following error:

An error occurred while updating the product(s) status.

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

How can I solve that and where can I check the problem?

**Solved:**

Needed to increase the size of `innodb_log_file_size`.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please mention magento version.

Comment: @PrashantValanda Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Comment: what error occur,give an screen of error

Comment: @AmitBera See screenshot. That is the only error I get.

Comment: @AmitBera I updated the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an access to code - you can debug this issue next way:

1. open file file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php`
2. change line

   ```
   $this->_getSession()
               ->addException($e, $this->__('An error occurred while updating the product(s) status.'));
   ```

   to

   ```
   $this->_getSession()
               ->addException($e, $this->__('An error occurred while updating the product(s) status.') . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
   ```
3. then try to change your products in admin again. You should see more clear error message after it.

Just as an idea - why it can occur - Maybe your products have different Attribute sets and some of Sets doesn't contain an attribute which you are trying to change.

Or it can be just some mysql issue. Database connection or sql query error.